# Does deflecting a fireball with a looting sword give better drops?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got 2 ghast tears after I thought I deflected a fireball back at the ghast (with my looting 3 sword).  But I was pretty close, so I might have just hit it. I'm not sure.

If I deflect a fireball with a looting sword and it kills the ghast, do I still get the looting bonus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**. If a mob is killed by something directly caused by the player (reflected ghast fireball, splash damage potion, fall damage after a hit, arrow, etc.) while the player holds a looting sword, it applies the looting bonus.

Comment: Oh, so if the mob's far enough away, I could shoot an arrow, quickly switch to my sword while the arrow's in midair, and then get the looting bonus when the arrow hits and kills the mob?

Comment: I dont think it would work by switching weapon. I cant remember if the game is coded this way but here is how I think it works. Each items in the game are programmed in a file we call a class. When an item (fireball, arrow, etc) is spawned or has an interaction with something else, variables are created/modified for this particular object. Variables leaving your sword or your bow are different and when they are applied, they are not applied to everything but only to the object that it interacted with.

Comment: It totally works. The bonus is applied from what item you currently have selected in your hotbar, not what is doing the killing. Switching in midair is the best way to maximize your drops from potion killing lots of mobs from your mob farm.

Comment: I use this all the time to get more drops from my farms - just use a crusher on them to get them low on health, then throw a damage potion, switch to your looting sword before it hits, and receive the loot!